# dynamic sql in oracle passing data para

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, dynamic-sql

I need to convert this in dynamic sql in oracle passing data para

```
Select * from Student
where effective_date = '30-APR-2022';

set serveroutput on;
declare
date_ varchar2(100) := '30-APR-2022';
sql_stmt varchar2 (10000);
begin
sql_stmt := 'select * from student
where effective_date = ''' ||to_char (date_, 'DD-MON-YYYY');
dbms_output.put_line(sql_stmt);
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```sql
set serveroutput on;
declare
  date_    varchar2(100) := '30-APR-2022';
  sql_stmt varchar2 (10000);
begin
  sql_stmt := 'select * from student where  effective_date = TO_DATE(''' || date_ || ''', ''DD-MON-YYYY'')';
  dbms_output.put_line(sql_stmt);
end;
/
```

or, if you are going to use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` with the dynamic SQL then you can use bind variables (which will help prevent SQL injection attacks):

```sql
set serveroutput on;
declare
  date_    varchar2(100) := '30-APR-2022';
  sql_stmt varchar2 (10000);
  v_col1   student.col1%TYPE;
  v_col2   student.col2%TYPE;
begin
  sql_stmt := 'select col1, col2 from student where effective_date = TO_DATE(:dt, ''DD-MON-YYYY'')';
  dbms_output.put_line(sql_stmt);
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt INTO v_col1, v_col2 USING date_;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_col1 || ', ' || v_col2);
end;
/
```

*(Assuming that there will only be a single row returned.)*

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8c562eef7f18e5256146d47365f11923)*